# Can you set up a one-on-one meeting on Outlook, but "forgot" to add the person's name to the invite?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

A person seemed to have messed up by a big mistake in the company, and can be subject to being fired, but he claimed, he actually took the action and invited somebody for a one-on-one meeting on Microsoft Outlook, but he just forgot to include that person's name / email.

We are using Outlook version 16.39.  Is it actually possible to set up a one-on-one meeting (so it is a meeting with only one other person), where you would be able to send out an invite, but you can "forgot" to add the person you are inviting?  I tried in my Outlook 16.39, and if I don't type in a person's name, Outlook would not allow me to click "Send" at all.  Is it possible to set up a meeting with one person but you don't include that person's name / email and be able to perceive that you send out the invite?

Here is how Outlook looks like if you don't type in any recipient:

[How Outlook looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zRD9.png)

How can a person not type in anything and be able to send it?

Comment: I deleted my answer. I know very well how Outlook works (and help my clients in this way). It is normally easy to distinguish between a user error and an Outlook software error and Outlook here was working.

Comment: @John sorry your answer was not really answering the question

Comment: I did answer the question properly. There was a user error and that is what I had posted.

Comment: @John so Outlook doesn't allow the user to click the Send button. But the "user error" allowed him to click the Send button. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No. the user did not (you say) add a recipient. So that is a user error.

Comment: He claimed he did not add a recipient but was able to send it.  How is that a user error.  It should be "Outlook does not allow it". If he said he did it, either he was lying or Outlook had a bug that behave like that to him.  Normally, even if the front end UI allows you to send it, the server will tell you NOT POSSIBLE and send back an error, so beyond reasonable doubt, it actually is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, it is not achieveable to set up a one-on-one meeting on Outlook without adding the person's name to the invite. We need to add other users as meeting participants so that the meeting information can be displayed on other users’ calendars.

Comment: right, it is like sending an email without an recipient and the system let you send it and report "successful" -- what does that mean?